# What is a best way to implement a SQL Server Job Scheduler

Tags: php, sql-server, backup, scheduler, schedule

I am getting some SQL Server database backups (`.bak`) daily and I need to restore the data from the backup daily to SQL Server, then remove that `.bak` file from the files.

What is the best way to do this? Is using PHP will make it easier?

Comment: You would need event driven scheduler, Something that will trigger your script as soon as *.bak file appear. I don't know if PHP has something link this, other technologies you would use is .NET with it's FileSystemWatcher. Maybe potentially worth to look is Jenkins also.